# Regex pattern to replace date and time node in xml of word document

Tags: regex, xml, vba, ms-word

I need to replace the date and time in xml file using regex pattern.

xml text would contain:

- w:date="2022-12-01T01:17:00Z"
- w:date="2022-12-01T02:17:00Z"
- w:date="2022-12-02T03:17:00Z"

possible regex pattern for the above would be:

- w:date="[\d\W]\w[\d\W]\w"

but it is not replacing anything and the resulted string remain intact in the following VBA code:

```
Sub ChangeDateTime()

    Dim sWOOXML As String
    
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.MultiLine = True
    
    objRegEx.Pattern = "w:date=" & Chr(34) & "[\d\W]\w[\d\W]\w" & Chr(34)
    
    sWOOXML = ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML
    sWOOXML = objRegEx.Replace(sWOOXML, "")
        
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertXML sWOOXML
    
    Beep
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `[\d\W]\w[\d\W]\w` regex prevents from matching since it only finds two repetitions of a digit or non-word char + a word char sequence between two double quotes, while you have many more chars there.

You can use

```vb
objRegEx.Pattern = "w:date=""\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}Z"""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7TyAaf/1). Note you may add a double quote to the string using a doubled `"`, no need to use `Chr(34)`.

This is a verbose pattern where `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits and `\d{4}` matches four digits, the rest is self-explanatory.